# How to get Header Response in angular 2 without external link?

Tags: angular, header

I would like to know how to get the get header in angular 2 in the same way as from the JSP you get the headers created by the servlet, for example:

```
response.getHeader ("name header");
```

Here i would like to do the same thing in angular without a call from an external link.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly get the headers from the response received .
When you fire a get request , the received response will contain headers.

```
http.get('API_URL')
  .subscribe((res:Response) => {
    console.log("headers are ",res.headers);
    // use the header values as you want
  });
```

Read more about Response Class 
https://angular.io/api/http/Response

Comment: I know, but i want get headers call without link.

Comment: What do you mean by link??

Comment: I said that I want get header from a call without a link call, as the same as JSP where you get headers call only write : response.getHeader("requesturihub")

Comment: So of you don't "call a link" (fire a request,) how will you get a response ? And if you dont get a response , what header do you want.
See how all the requests in Angular 2 are cold requests by default
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815886/difference-between-cold-or-hot-http-requests